# How find this number of permutation such $|a_{k}-k|\ge\dfrac{n-1}{2}$

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

let $n$ is give postive integer,Find the number of the  $(a_{1},a_{2},\cdots,a_{n})$ be a permutation of $(1,2,3,\cdots,n)$.such
$$|a_{k}-k|\ge\dfrac{n-1}{2}$$for any $k=1,2,\cdots,n$

This is Mathematics olympiad question in Shanghai in 2014 last problem.and maybe this is old problem.because I fell is very  the impression.

Thank you

Comment: What have you tried? You might first want to see what the answer is for a fixed $k$.

Comment: If $n$ is even, what must $a_{n/2}$ be? then $a_{n/2-1}$? etc. If $n$ is odd, what must $a_{(n+1)/2}$ be?

Comment: *Hint*: Show that the number of permutations for $n=2k$ is $1$  (in fact, $(n-k,n-k+1,\cdots,n,1,2,\cdots,k)$ is the only permutation) and for $n=2k+1$ is $2^k.$

Answer (score 2):

Let $S_n$ be the number of desired permutations, then

**Claim**: $$S_{2k}=1 \;\; \text{and} \;\; S_{2k+1}=2^k.$$

Assume that the location of each $1 \leq i \leq n$ is given by $b_i.$ For example, in the permutation $213$ of $\{1,2,3\},$ $1$ is located in the second place i.e. $b_1=2$ and $2$ is located in the first place i.e. $b_2=1$ and finally, $b_3=3.$

***Case 1***. Let $n=2k.$ The condition is now $|a_i-i| \geq k$ which implies that for each $1 \leq i \leq k,$ we have $\boxed{b_i \geq k+i}$ that is, $1$ has to be in place numbered at least $k+1,$ $2$ has to be in place numbered at least $k+2,$ and finally $k$ has to be placed numbered at least $2k.$ But as there're $k$ numbers $\{1,2,\cdots,k\}$ and then $k$ places with the above conditions that implies that $\{1,2,\cdots,k\}$ have to placed in $k+1,k+2,\cdots,2k$ locations, i.e. $b_i=k+i.$ Likewise, $\{k+1,k+2,\cdots,2k\}$ have to placed in $1,2,\cdots,k$ locations i.e. $b_j=j-k$ for $k+1 \leq j \leq 2k.$ Hence there's only one such permutation $(k+1,k+2,\cdots,2k,1,2,\cdots,k)$ satisfying the condition $|a_i-i| \geq k.$

***Case 2***. Let $n=2k+1.$ The condition is now $|a_i-i| \geq k.$ Here, the location of $b_{k+1}$ is either $1$ or $2k.$ Assume, $b_{k+1}=1,$ then $b_{k+j} \geq j$ for $2 \leq j \leq k+1$ but as there're $k$ numbers $\{k+2,k+3,\cdots,2k+1\}$ that have to placed with the mentioned restriction the only possible permutation is $(k+1,k+2,k+3,\cdots,2k,2k+1, -,-,\cdots,-)$ and the blank spaces are going to be filled with $\{1,2,\cdots,k\},$ i.e. $\boxed{b_t \geq k+t+1}$ for $1\leq t \leq k.$

*Lemma:* The number of permutations of $\{1,2,\cdots,k\}$ with the location restrictions $b_t \geq k+t+1$ for $1 \leq t \leq k$ is $2^{k-1}.$

*Proof of the lemma*: Let $T_k$ be the number of desired permutations. Again because of the main restriction $|a_i-i| \geq k$ the location of $k$ i.e. $b_k$ can either be $2k+1$ or $2k.$ So $b_k$ has $2$ possible locations. Similarly, $b_{t}$ has $(2k+1)-(k+t+1)+1=k-t+1$ possible locations where $1 \leq t \leq k.$ If $b_k=2k+1$ then the number of desired permutations of $\{1,2,\cdots,k-1\}$ with the lemma condition will be $T_{k-1}$ and if $b_t=2k$ the the number desired permutations of $\{1,2,\cdots,k-1\}$ in locations $k+2,k+3,\cdots,2k-1,2k+1$ is in one-to-one correspondence with the previous number of permutations with is $T_{k-1}.$ Therefore, $T_k=2T_{k-1}$ and $T_1=1.$ Then $T_k=2^{k-1}T_1=2^{k-1}.$

Using the lemma, $S_{2k+1}=2T_{k}$ because as we said before $b_{k+1}$ has $2$ possible locations and when $b_{k+1}=2k+1$ the argument will be quite similar but we would have to work with $\{k+2,k+3,\cdots,2k+1\}$ instead of $\{1,2,\cdots,k\}.$ Hence, $S_{2k+1}=2^k.$